# multiple instances of a jquery Vertical show case slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just using a vertical show case slider here is my source code :

```
var Slider = (function() {

var $container = $( '#ps-container' ),
    $contentwrapper = $container.children( 'div.ps-contentwrapper' ),
    // the items (description elements for the slides/products)
    $items = $contentwrapper.children( 'div.ps-content' ),
    itemsCount = $items.length,
    $slidewrapper = $container.children( 'div.ps-slidewrapper' ),
    // the slides (product images)
    $slidescontainer = $slidewrapper.find( 'div.ps-slides' ),
    $slides = $slidescontainer.children( 'div' ),
    // navigation arrows
    $navprev = $slidewrapper.find( 'nav > a.ps-prev' ),
    $navnext = $slidewrapper.find( 'nav > a.ps-next' ),
    // current index for items and slides
    current = 0,
    // checks if the transition is in progress
    isAnimating = false,
    // support for CSS transitions
    support = Modernizr.csstransitions,

    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
        'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition' : 'transitionend'
    },
    // its name
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],

    init = function() {

        // show first item
        var $currentItem = $items.eq( current ),
            $currentSlide = $slides.eq( current ),
            initCSS = {
                top : 0,
                zIndex : 999
            };

        $currentItem.css( initCSS );
        $currentSlide.css( initCSS );

        // update nav images
        updateNavImages();

        // initialize some events
        initEvents();

    },
    updateNavImages = function() {

        // updates the background image for the navigation arrows
        var configPrev = ( current > 0 ) ? $slides.eq( current - 1 ).css( 'background-image' ) : $slides.eq( itemsCount - 1 ).css( 'background-image' ),
            configNext = ( current < itemsCount - 1 ) ? $slides.eq( current + 1 ).css( 'background-image' ) : $slides.eq( 0 ).css( 'background-image' );

        $navprev.css( 'background-image', configPrev );
        $navnext.css( 'background-image', configNext );

    },
    initEvents = function() {

        $navprev.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            if( !isAnimating ) {

                slide( 'prev' );

            }
            return false;

        } );

        $navnext.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            if( !isAnimating ) {

                slide( 'next' );

            }
            return false;

        } );

        // transition end event
        $items.on( transEndEventName, removeTransition );
        $slides.on( transEndEventName, removeTransition );

    },
    removeTransition = function() {

        isAnimating = false;
        $(this).removeClass('ps-move');

    },
    slide = function( dir ) {

        isAnimating = true;

        var $currentItem = $items.eq( current ),
            $currentSlide = $slides.eq( current );

        // update current value
        if( dir === 'next' ) {

            ( current < itemsCount - 1 ) ? ++current : current = 0;

        }
        else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

            ( current > 0 ) ? --current : current = itemsCount - 1;

        }
            // new item that will be shown
        var $newItem = $items.eq( current ),
            // new slide that will be shown
            $newSlide = $slides.eq( current );

        // position the new item up or down the viewport depending on the direction
        $newItem.css( {
            top : ( dir === 'next' ) ? '-100%' : '100%',
            zIndex : 999
        } );

        $newSlide.css( {
            top : ( dir === 'next' ) ? '100%' : '-100%',
            zIndex : 999
        } );

        setTimeout( function() {

            // move the current item and slide to the top or bottom depending on the direction 
            $currentItem.addClass( 'ps-move' ).css( {
                top : ( dir === 'next' ) ? '100%' : '-100%',
                zIndex : 1
            } );

            $currentSlide.addClass( 'ps-move' ).css( {
                top : ( dir === 'next' ) ? '-100%' : '100%',
                zIndex : 1
            } );

            // move the new ones to the main viewport
            $newItem.addClass( 'ps-move' ).css( 'top', 0 );
            $newSlide.addClass( 'ps-move' ).css( 'top', 0 );

            // if no CSS transitions set the isAnimating flag to false
            if( !support ) {

                isAnimating = false;

            }

        }, 0 );

        // update nav images
        updateNavImages();

    };

return { init : init }; })();
```

> and in html here is my code :
>   {% for i,menu in zipped_data %}

```
        <div class="ps-contentwrapper">

            <div class="ps-content">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="ps-content">

                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="ps-content">
                <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="ps-content">
                <p></p>
            </div>



        </div><!-- /ps-contentwrapper -->

        <div class="ps-slidewrapper">

            <div class="ps-slides">
            {% for photo in photos_list|lookup:i %} 
                <div style="background-image:url('{{photo.get_display_url }}');"></div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="ps-prev" ></a>
                <a href="#" class="ps-next" ></a>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /ps-slidewrapper -->

    </section><!-- /ps-container -->
```

{% endfor %}
How can I make multiple instances of this slider on the same page .

> so I want multiple instances of the section but it's not working

If any body can help me in this please

Comment: @skobaljic  skobaljic [skobaljic]  [ http://stackoverflow.com/users/1386703/skobaljic ] if you can help me in this please or if you can just give me hints to do it thank you in advance regards ...